# StreamWriter stops writing in the meddle of writing to a text file halfway

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a list that holds 14 values coming from SQL server table, and I am looping to pass values to the StreamWriter object with WriteLine to write the values in the required format on a text file. My issue is, while on debug I can see all values being added to my print variable; however, when the loop completes it only prints 9 values and the 9th value gets cut on the text file. Please refer to my screenshots.

```
Using resource As New DevelopmentEntities
            Dim sw As StreamWriter
            Dim list As New List(Of ContactU)
            list = resource.ContactUs.ToList()
            sw = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(outputpath & "Web_ContactUs_" & countValue & ".txt", True)
            For Each item In list
                list = list.OrderBy(Function(x) item.Submitters_First_Name_First).ToList()
                countValue = countValue + 1
                If Not item.Entry_Id.ToString Is "" Then
                    Dim valueItem = list
                    Dim ssnValue = "UANPF" & item.Last_4_of_SSN.TrimStart.TrimEnd
                    Dim raw_date As Date = item.Entry_Date.TrimEnd
                    Dim entry_date As Date = raw_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                    Dim concatinatedFilepath = textfilepath & item.Submitters_First_Name_First.Replace(" ", "_").TrimStart.TrimEnd _
                        & "_" & item.Submitters_Last_Name_Last.Replace(" ", "_").TrimStart.TrimEnd _
                        & "_" & item.Last_4_of_SSN.TrimStart _
                        & "_" & countValue
                    Dim print = filetype &
                        "|" & concatinatedFilepath &
                        ".txt" &
                        "|" & ssnValue &
                        "|" & incoming &
                        "|" & addresschange &
                        "|" & entry_date &
                        "|" & ITP
                    sw.WriteLine(print)
                Else
                    'Do nothing will clear invalid data
                End If
            Next

        End Using
```

[image: Visual Studio on Debug mode][image: What it prints on the text file]

Comment: Where do you close `sw`?

Comment: @Steeeve I am sorry I thought I captured the top part, I am using a Using statement. And I copied my code too. Let me know if you need the whole method.

Comment: I can't see any using block for `sw`

Comment: @Steeeve Oh man oh man! facepalm! I just realized I don't have sw.flash() sw.Close() method. You're a lifesaver ... lol by the way do I need the sw.flash?

Comment: If you put sw in a using block, you don't need neither `Flush()` nor `Close()`

Comment: @Steeeve perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Using resource As New DevelopmentEntities
        Dim sw As StreamWriter
        Dim list As New List(Of ContactU)
        list = resource.ContactUs.ToList()
        sw = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(outputpath & "Web_ContactUs_" & countValue & ".txt", True)
        For Each item In list
            list = list.OrderBy(Function(x) item.Submitters_First_Name_First).ToList()
            countValue = countValue + 1
            If Not item.Entry_Id.ToString Is "" Then
                Dim valueItem = list
                Dim ssnValue = "UANPF" & item.Last_4_of_SSN.TrimStart.TrimEnd
                Dim raw_date As Date = item.Entry_Date.TrimEnd
                Dim entry_date As Date = raw_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                Dim concatinatedFilepath = textfilepath & item.Submitters_First_Name_First.Replace(" ", "_").TrimStart.TrimEnd _
                    & "_" & item.Submitters_Last_Name_Last.Replace(" ", "_").TrimStart.TrimEnd _
                    & "_" & item.Last_4_of_SSN.TrimStart _
                    & "_" & countValue
                Dim print = filetype &
                    "|" & concatinatedFilepath &
                    ".txt" &
                    "|" & ssnValue &
                    "|" & incoming &
                    "|" & addresschange &
                    "|" & entry_date &
                    "|" & ITP
                sw.WriteLine(print)
            Else
                'Do nothing will clear invalid data
            End If
        Next
        sw.Close()
    End Using
```